# Howto add onclick event to button in listview added by addheaderView?

Tags: android

I'm using a listview. Before adding the main list items to the listview, i add a header with  to the listview using addheaderview(v). header have two buttons.

In logcat..it gives problem at 
btnhome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

and it force close.
plz help me where is error in below code.

waiting for your reply
thanx in advance

```
enter code here
```

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.games_by_category);

        Global globalclass=((Global)getApplicationContext());
        globalclass.setpageno(0);                   
        lstview =(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);      

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);            
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        //View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        v.setMinimumHeight(10);
        lstview.addHeaderView(v);

        btnhome=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnHome);
        btnhome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                btnhome.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                Global globalclass=((Global)getApplicationContext());
                Intent inte=new Intent(GamesByCatActivity.this,HotGamesActivity.class);
                startActivity(inte);                    
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get the Buttons from the header view and set the onClickListener.

```
View header;
Button headerButton = header.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
headerButton.setOnClickListener(this);
listView.addHeaderView(header);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand your problem. What do you want to do? If you have `ListView` and header then you use `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:id="@+id/_lv_babies" >
    </ListView>
          <RelativeLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/blue_email"
        >
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Edit" android:textSize="15dp" android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:id="@+id/_btn_edit"/>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Add" android:textSize="15dp" android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" android:textColor="@color/black"
             android:id="@+id/_btn_add"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the example you can use like this.

Comment: hii thx for reply.. i  added a addheaderview to my list. n that header hav buttons. i want onclick event on these button. how can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
For your button click....if its works then tick on right click or accept my answer. 
protected void setXmlComponents(){
        _btn_add =(Button)findViewById(R.id._btn_add);
        _btn_edit =(Button)findViewById(R.id._btn_edit);
            }
    protected void setListener(){
        _btn_add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            }
        });
      _btn_edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: this is not solution of my problem :(

Comment: Include this in your xml below listview                          <include layout="@layout/header"  />                              edit your code given below                                   btnhome=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnHome); 
 btnhome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
   public void onClick(View v)  
            { 
              
          } 
        });

Comment: i added this but still it force close.. :(